# Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' not compatible with net6.0

Tags: .net-6.0

I am getting below warning on building my solution. This package is not yet supported in net6.0.

```
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.9' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Are there any alternative for it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use ASP.NET WebApi in a .NET 6 projecdt.  As the warning suggest, that's not a good idea. You should use ASP.NET Core.